# What does "slogar" mean, or what could the word be?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

I keep hearing an ad on the radio for wayfair.com that starts out:

> wayfair punto com tiene todo que necessita para **slogar**...

However, I can't find any translation for the word "**slogar**", so I feel like I have it wrong. The only thing I can think of is that it's actually "para su logar" but I can't distinguish that even when listening very carefully.

Does anyone know what word this is?

Comment: Looking at what they sell could it be _su hogar_?

Comment: _SL_ at the beggining of words is not present in native Spanish phonology. It would most likely become _eslogar_. Maybe it's _su hogar_ (your home, polite). Otherwise it could be a foreign word or a wordplay.

Comment: It must be su hogar. I'll listen again and see if that's it.

Comment: https://www.ispot.tv/ad/7C5e/wayfair-the-musical-spanish

Comment: Si eso es! Is she saying "su hogar"? Gracias.

Comment: In this one the opening sentence is "Encuentra todo lo que necesitas para tu hogar en wayfair.com"

Comment: Thank you @rsanchez. Can you put this in an answer and I'll mark it?

Comment: @rsanchez va, anímate a contestar, que parece que tienes todos los ingredientes para redactar una respuesta completa :)

Comment: Sí, estoy esperando a que respondiera por lo que puedo marcarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in comments, you misheard the last part of the sentence, where they are talking about **hogar** (=home).

What is really being said is either of these:

> wayfair punto com tiene todo lo que necesita para **su hogar**...
>
> wayfair punto com tiene todo lo que necesita**s** para **tu hogar**...

Don't blame yourself, since the spelling in a related [video](https://www.ispot.tv/ad/7C5e/wayfair-the-musical-spanish) linked [by rsanchez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17824/what-does-slogar-mean-or-what-could-the-word-be#comment25772_17824) is not easy.

Note we understand this as Spanish speakers because the context helps us focus on the topic and interpolate what words could be matching in this context. As always, is not just what you hear but what you expect to hear in a given circumstance.

For example, in a given circumstance you can be introduced to someone and at the end of the conversation say:

> - Mucho gusto en conocerle.  <sub>(Nice to meet you)</sub>
> - Igual miente.

In this context, you would always expect the second person to say *igualmente* (meaning *so do I* or *me too*). The joke is to say "igual miente" (*you may be lying*), a sentence which sounds almost equally but has a complete different meaning.

Comment: Though you weren't the first to give the right answer, yours is by far the most thorough and helpful, and you actually answered in an answer.